# iOS ContactsUI Framework Permissions

Tags: ios, permissions, app-store, submission, contactsui

I'm fetching contacts using `CNContactPickerViewController`, and it seems that iOS doesn't automatically ask me for access permissions.

Do I really need permissions for using `CNContactPickerViewController` or do I need to request for permissions manually?

If I need permissions for this, will my app get rejected if I submit this app to the App Store and if I did not ask for Contacts permissions?

*Note*: There is nothing stated in the [ContactsUI Framework documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/ContactsUI_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that using ContactsUI API doesn't need permissions since it states in [Contacts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/) that permissions will only show (the first time only) on calls to `CNContactStore`.

> Users can grant or deny access to contact data on a per-application basis. Any call to `CNContactStore` will block the application while the user is being asked to grant or deny access. Note that the user is prompted only the first time access is requested; any subsequent `CNContactStore` calls use the existing permissions.

**Source**:

Apple's [Contacts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/)

Answer (score 13):

Permission is not required when using `CNContactPickerViewController`.

The documentation for [CNContactPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/) states:

> The app using contact picker view does not need access to the user’s contacts and the user will not be prompted for “grant permission” access. The app has access only to the user’s final selection.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Contacts` & `ContactsUI` frameworks, you need to check authorization status with this method: `CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType()`. And then you check for enum value `CNAuthorizationStatus`, you want `.Authorized`.

If status is `.Denied` or `.NotDetermined` you can request access to contacts with method `requestAccessForEntityType()`, see `CNContactStore` class for info.

Answer (score -1):

Check this [Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html). In short, you need to check (switch-case) for `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()`, and if value is `kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` the user has granted access to their contacts.
If authorization status is `kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, you can even request address book access using method `[CNContactStore requestAccessForEntityType:completionHandler:]`.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using `Contacts` and `ContactsUI` frameworks since `AddressBook` framework is already deprecated. And I don't think they have a similar API.

Comment: Sorry, I always used this code so I did not read carefully..
In short, when using Contact & ContactUI frameworks, you need to check authorization status with this method: `CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType()`. And then you check for enum value `CNAuthorizationStatus`, you want `.Authorized`.

Comment: No worries. I just found a statement in Apple docs which may indicate that ContactsUI Framework does not need permission: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36788160/4897074

Comment: Regardless, you should always check if app has the required permission to access contacts, because user can change the authorization state of the app through the device Settings.app.